# Customize SonataAdminBundle base_edit_form.html.twig

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin

I would like to show the map in the form generated by Sonata Admin Bundle

This is my formMapper,

```
class PlaceInfoAdmin extends Admin
{
    public function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
    {
    $formMapper
        ->with('General')
        ->add('lati')
        ->add('longi')
        ->add('name')
```

I am using ivory google map API.

Simplifying what I want to do,

1. put this code at the last of template used by PlaceInfoAdmin

   {{ ivory_google_api([
       data.map,
       data.form.field.vars['autocomplete']
   ])}}
2. put this code between rendered the cide of `longi` and `name`.

   {{  ivory_google_map(data.map) }}

Now I research the twig files and found out maybe form is rendered by base_edit_form.html.twig,

However where should I alter?? or How can I find this twig is called by PlaceInfoAdmin?? (not by another ****Admin class)

```
{% block form %}
    {{ sonata_block_render_event('sonata.admin.edit.form.top', { 'admin': admin, 'object': object }) }}

    {% set url = admin.id(object) is not null ? 'edit' : 'create' %}

    {% if not admin.hasRoute(url)%}
        <div>
            {{ "form_not_available"|trans({}, "SonataAdminBundle") }}
        </div>
    {% else %}
        <form
              {% if sonata_admin.adminPool.getOption('form_type') == 'horizontal' %}class="form-horizontal"{% endif %}
              role="form"
              action="{% block sonata_form_action_url %}{{ admin.generateUrl(url, {'id': admin.id(object), 'uniqid': admin.uniqid, 'subclass': app.request.get('subclass')}) }}{% endblock %}"
              {% if form.vars.multipart %} enctype="multipart/form-data"{% endif %}
              method="POST"
              {% if not sonata_admin.adminPool.getOption('html5_validate') %}novalidate="novalidate"{% endif %}
              {% block sonata_form_attributes %}{% endblock %}
              >

            {{ include('SonataAdminBundle:Helper:render_form_dismissable_errors.html.twig') }}

            {% block sonata_pre_fieldsets %}
                <div class="row">
            {% endblock %}

            {% block sonata_tab_content %}
                {% set has_tab = ((admin.formtabs|length == 1 and admin.formtabs|keys[0] != 'default') or admin.formtabs|length > 1 ) %}

                <div class="col-md-12">
                    {% if has_tab %}
                        <div class="nav-tabs-custom">
                            <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
                                {% for name, form_tab in admin.formtabs %}
                                    <li{% if loop.index == 1 %} class="active"{% endif %}><a href="#tab_{{ admin.uniqid }}_{{ loop.index }}" data-toggle="tab"><i class="fa fa-exclamation-circle has-errors hide" aria-hidden="true"></i> {{ name|trans({}, form_tab.translation_domain ?: admin.translationDomain) }}</a></li>
                                {% endfor %}
                            </ul>
                            <div class="tab-content">
                                {% for code, form_tab in admin.formtabs %}
                                    <div class="tab-pane fade{% if loop.first %} in active{% endif %}" id="tab_{{ admin.uniqid }}_{{ loop.index }}">
                                        <div class="box-body  container-fluid">
                                            <div class="sonata-ba-collapsed-fields">
                                                {% if form_tab.description != false %}
                                                    <p>{{ form_tab.description|raw }}</p>
                                                {% endif %}

                                                {{ form_helper.render_groups(admin, form, form_tab['groups'], has_tab) }}
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                {% endfor %}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    {% else %}
                        {{ form_helper.render_groups(admin, form, admin.formtabs['default'].groups, has_tab) }}
                    {% endif %}
                </div>
            {% endblock %}

            {% block sonata_post_fieldsets %}
                </div>
            {% endblock %}

            {{ form_rest(form) }}

            {% block formactions %}
                <div class="sonata-ba-form-actions well well-small form-actions">
                {% block sonata_form_actions %}
                    {% if app.request.isxmlhttprequest %}
                        {% if admin.id(object) is not null %}
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="btn_update"><i class="fa fa-save" aria-hidden="true"></i> {{ 'btn_update'|trans({}, 'SonataAdminBundle') }}</button>
                        {% else %}
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="btn_create"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i> {{ 'btn_create'|trans({}, 'SonataAdminBundle') }}</button>
                        {% endif %}
                    {% else %}
                        {% if admin.supportsPreviewMode %}
                            <button class="btn btn-info persist-preview" name="btn_preview" type="submit">
                                <i class="fa fa-eye" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                {{ 'btn_preview'|trans({}, 'SonataAdminBundle') }}
                            </button>
                        {% endif %}
                        {% if admin.id(object) is not null %}
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="btn_update_and_edit"><i class="fa fa-save" aria-hidden="true"></i> {{ 'btn_update_and_edit_again'|trans({}, 'SonataAdminBundle') }}</button>

                            {% if admin.hasroute('list') and admin.isGranted('LIST') %}
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="btn_update_and_list"><i class="fa fa-save"></i> <i class="fa fa-list" aria-hidden="true"></i> {{ 'btn_update_and_return_to_list'|trans({}, 'SonataAdminBundle') }}</button>
                            {% endif %}

                            {% if admin.hasroute('delete') and admin.isGranted('DELETE', object) %}
                                {{ 'delete_or'|trans({}, 'SonataAdminBundle') }}
                                <a class="btn btn-danger" href="{{ admin.generateObjectUrl('delete', object) }}"><i class="fa fa-minus-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i> {{ 'link_delete'|trans({}, 'SonataAdminBundle') }}</a>
                            {% endif %}

                            {% if admin.isAclEnabled() and admin.hasroute('acl') and admin.isGranted('MASTER', object) %}
                                <a class="btn btn-info" href="{{ admin.generateObjectUrl('acl', object) }}"><i class="fa fa-users" aria-hidden="true"></i> {{ 'link_edit_acl'|trans({}, 'SonataAdminBundle') }}</a>
                            {% endif %}
                        {% else %}
                            {% if admin.hasroute('edit') and admin.isGranted('EDIT') %}
                                <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit" name="btn_create_and_edit"><i class="fa fa-save" aria-hidden="true"></i> {{ 'btn_create_and_edit_again'|trans({}, 'SonataAdminBundle') }}</button>
                            {% endif %}
                            {% if admin.hasroute('list') and admin.isGranted('LIST') %}
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="btn_create_and_list"><i class="fa fa-save"></i> <i class="fa fa-list" aria-hidden="true"></i> {{ 'btn_create_and_return_to_list'|trans({}, 'SonataAdminBundle') }}</button>
                            {% endif %}
                            <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit" name="btn_create_and_create"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i> {{ 'btn_create_and_create_a_new_one'|trans({}, 'SonataAdminBundle') }}</button>
                        {% endif %}
                    {% endif %}
                {% endblock %}
                </div>
            {% endblock formactions %}
        </form>
    {% endif%}

    {{ sonata_block_render_event('sonata.admin.edit.form.bottom', { 'admin': admin, 'object': object }) }}

{% endblock %}
{% endblock %}
```

Ho

Answer (score 1):

Create a template that extends `base_edit.html.twig`:

```
{% extends 'SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:base_edit.html.twig' %}

{% block form %}

    {# your custom code #}
    {{ parent() }}

{% endblock %}
```

Then to make sure only the admin you want uses that template pass it in the definition of your admin service with a `setTemplate` call:

```
librinfo_crm.admin.contact:
        class: Librinfo\CRMBundle\Admin\ContactAdmin
        arguments: [~, Librinfo\CRMBundle\Entity\Contact, SonataAdminBundle:CRUD]
        tags:
            -   name: sonata.admin
                manager_type: orm
                group: Customers Relationship Management
                label: librinfo.crm.contact_admin.label
                label_translator_strategy: blast_core.label.strategy.librinfo
        calls:                    
            - [ setTemplate, [edit, LibrinfoCRMBundle:OrganismAdmin:edit.html.twig]]
```